# Homebrew seemingly dead - how to reinstall or repair?

Tags: homebrew

I just jumped into iTerm2 to install yarn, and did the normal, which is a `brew update` followed by a `brew install` and received an error ... so I tried a `brew doctor` and got the same error ... here is the output:

```
~ $brew update
Already up-to-date.
michael on Mikes-MacBook-Pro (c for commands)
~ $brew install yarn
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:12:in `require_relative': /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/setup.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
<<<<<<< HEAD
^~
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
michael on Mikes-MacBook-Pro (c for commands)
~ $brew doctor
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:12:in `require_relative': /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/bundler/setup.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
<<<<<<< HEAD
^~
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
michael on Mikes-MacBook-Pro (c for commands)
~ $
```

Here is the contents of load_path.rb ... I see the value of "require_relative" but I have no clue what is wrong with it since I don't understand the context of its reference ...

```
# typed: true
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "pathname"

HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH = Pathname(__dir__).parent.realpath.freeze

require_relative "../utils/gems"
Homebrew.setup_gem_environment!(setup_path: false)

$LOAD_PATH.push HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH.to_s unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH.to_s)
require_relative "../vendor/bundle/bundler/setup"
$LOAD_PATH.uniq!

# Block any gem loading by bypassing rubygem's `require`.
# Helps make sure we don't accidentally use things not in bundler's load path.
# Bundler 2.2.7+ and non-standalone mode both do this automatically.
# https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/5841761974bef324a33ef1cb650bbf8a2457805b/bundler/lib/bundler/installer/standalone.rb#L55-L63
if Kernel.private_method_defined?(:gem_original_require)
  Kernel.send(:remove_method, :require)
  Kernel.send(:define_method, :require, Kernel.instance_method(:gem_original_require))
  Kernel.send(:private, :require)
end
```

I googled how to reinstall Homebrew but none of the answers to that question looked remotely inviting ... does anyone recognize what I'm seeing here who could offer some insightful options that I could try?

Thank you,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to completely remove Homebrew and reinstall it as well as all programs that I had previously installed with Homebrew.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```